# Php - Storing Session Id in database

Tags: php, session

I have a table where users can upload files without logging into the application as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE files (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  path VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  session_id VARCHAR NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

To ensure users can only download the files they upload I'm using a session id - note there is no need to keep track of the file longer than the session.

The question is should I store the session id directly in the database i.e `session_id()` or should I store a unique id in a session variable e.g.  `$_SESSION['session_id'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)` and store that in the database instead?

Does it make any difference to the end use case?

Comment: Save unique param to Cookies and same param to database. Cookies stays until deleted or expired, session ends after user closes browser

Comment: Cookies is definitely the way to go. DB can serve as a backup if you're capturing extra params like IP and User Agent.

Comment: @Justinas There is no need to keep track of the file longer than the session.

Comment: @PatrickQ well it could be an ajax upload which presents the user to preview the file they just uploaded. However since a file can be previewed using its id then a malicisous user could simply enter the download url and change ids - not so pointless now is it.